# Is it possible to calculate how far vapor particles go?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, diffusion

Is it possible to calculate how far vapor particles go? I'm curious about vape pens and how far their smell goes. I thought if I think about it in terms of particles maybe I can come up with something. I'm not even sure if it's possible to do this. Thought I'd ask someone here.

Comment: There is no limit of how far a vapor molecule can go, as long as there is enough time. Nevertheless, Graham's Law states that the rate of the diffusion of a gas is inversely proportional to the square root of its molar mass.

Comment: Suppose im standing 1 block away from my neighbor's house and he's burning wood and I can smell it very well. But, If I walk back another block I can smell it less because, im assuming there are fewer vaper particles in the air at that distance away. So im stuck on the first part of your sentence when you say that there's no limit of how far a vapor molecule can go. Are you saying that a vaper module, like when you're burning wood, can go on forever? Like someone 100 blocks away could be exposed to the burning wood vaper moclues.

Comment: Gas molecules tend to diffuse. In this sense, they keep moving forever. Fermi proposed a very interesting problem which asks "When you take a single breath, (on average) how many molecules of gas you intake would have come from the dying breath of Caesar?". You can find other versions of this problem in textbooks such as Gilbert Castellan's Thermodynamics.